# Assigning to an attached property using a child element

Tags: silverlight, xaml, attached-properties

Regular (not attached) properties in XAML can be assigned either as an attribute or as child element.

Example:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="Blue">Some text</TextBlock>
```

Or:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Foreground>
        <SolidColorBrush>Blue</SolidColorBrush>
    </TextBlock.Foreground>
    Some text
</TextBlock>
```

Since attached properties are usually simple, I only see examples of assigning to them using an attribute, example:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1">Some text</TextBlock>
```

But is it possible to assign to an attached property using a child element?

I have a custom control that has an attached property of a complex (class) type. Since I can't specify the value in an attribute, I'm not sure how to assign to it from XAML.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is called the [property element syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788723.aspx#property_element_syntax) and yes, you can set attached properties using the element attribute syntax:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Grid.Column>1</Grid.Column>
        ABC
</TextBlock>
```